# MdDialogContainer_Host.html:1 ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Tags: angular, angular-material2

So i'm trying to using MdDialog from angular material in an Angular 2 app. I receive a response from the dialog box and based on the response make an http call to delete data. I then make another http call to refresh the page afterwards but end up with the error below

**MdDialogContainer_Host.html:1 ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges**

I am not sure what is causing the ViewDestroyed error. Below is the code from my main component that calls the DeleteProjectComponent which contains the MdDialog

```
 onDeleteClicked(id) {
    this.project_id = id;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteProjectComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.response = result;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      if (this.response) {
        //this.deleteProject();
        // Function for DELETE request
        this.projectService.deleteProject(this.project_id).subscribe(data => {
          // Check if delete request worked
          if (!data.success) {
            this.message = data.message; // Return error message
            this._flashMessagesService.show(this.message, { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 1500 });
          } else {
            this.message = data.message; // Return success message
            this._flashMessagesService.show(this.message, { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 1500 });
            this.getAllProjects();
          }
        });
      }
    });

<h2 md-dialog-title>Delete project?</h2>
<div md-dialog-content>
  <div>
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete project?</p>
  </div>
  <div md-dialog-actions>
    <button md-raised-button md-dialog-close>No</button>
    <!-- Can optionally provide a result for the closing dialog. -->
    <button md-raised-button color="primary" [md-dialog-close]="true">Yes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `detectChanges()` there?

Comment: @BeetleJuice It was part of the error message

Comment: I'm talking about your code: `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`

Comment: it was a solution someone suggested on another platform but it turned out not working. With or without it, the problem persists